# String.split won't deal with the spaces at the first

Tags: java

```
String test="   Begin with spaces";   

for(String n:test.split("\\s"))              
    System.out.println(n);
```

The output is:

> Begin
>
> with
>
> space

I want to delete all the space, but it creates null strings. I can't use trim at first, So what's the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Why can't you use trim?

Comment: what i wanna do is to split the sentence and put it into array

Comment: It creates empty strings, not null ones.

Comment: @user1261718, ok, just FYI, you can call trim first, and then split the result of that.  Trim does not prevent you from splitting the resulting string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.split("      Begin with spaces", null);
```

return :

```
["Begin", "with", "spaces"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the output:

Begin

with

spaces

Then the code I would use is:

```
String test = "Begin with spaces";
for(String n:test.split(" "))
    System.out.println(n);
```

so just try using " " instead of /s

if you want to then throw them into one string just do:

```
String str = "";
String test = "Begin with spaces"
for(String n:test.split(" "))
    str = str+n;

System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: the output is the same. there are null elements at first. I wanna know if there exist some methods other than split can split and deal with spaces

Comment: a good way to find a problem is to list your inputs and your outputs, i know what your input is but I'm confused what exactly you are trying to do with the string? you want to delete all of the spaces?

Comment: oh geez. i found that stackoverflow deleted 2 spaces before the word "Begin" and 3 empty lines in the output. the problem i have is that split create null String elements, but i don't want them

Comment: they are not null strings, they are empty strings. you have set of "", not set of null.

Answer (score 1):

The built-in `String.split` method is really kind of crazy.  It sounds like you'd be better off using [Guava's](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) [`Splitter`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter):

```
Iterable<String> strings = Splitter
  .on(CharMatcher.WHITESPACE)
  .trimResults()
  .omitEmptyStrings()
  .split(myString);
```